VS Code autocomplete swapping between two options, when quick suggestions set to inline. Is there any way to stop it?
This question is not about how to disable the VS Code autocomplete functionality. I do not want to disable autocomplete completely.
This is how VS Code is currently configured in regards to quick suggestions:

Current Behaviour:

Visual Studio Code autocomplete switches between two options with each keypress. (Assuming there are two or more possible matches for words.) I am not sure exactly how those two options are chosen in the case where there are 3 or more possibilities.

Because the selected option switches with each keystroke, it is difficult to hit tab to get autocompletion of a word. One has to stop typing, see if the correct autocomplete option is selected, and if not, type another character to get it to "swap" to the other available option.


If there are more than 2 matches, then the user can press CTRL+Space to get the full list of options.
At least - this is how my VS Code is setup.

Is there a way to prevent VS Code autocomplete from switching between the two options?

It would be much more useful if it just selected the closest match and held that value until enough characters were typed to change the best match word.
Here's a screenshot to show you the behaviour I am seeing.


After pressing CTRL+Space

To clarify how I would expect it to behave:

Hold SessionStartMessage as the autocomplete auto-selected suggestion while the characters S, e, s, s, i, o, n are typed
Switch to SessionEndMessage when the characters SessionE have been typed


I cannot reproduce the switching between two options. I enabled inline quick suggestions for javascript, then opened a new JS editor and typed co and got "confirm", then typed n and it stayed on "confirm" even though there are several other things it could have gone to. can you repro what I'm seeing? if you can, I suspect this to be a specific behaviour of the language support extension you're using for whatever language this is (python?).

@starball It's possible that it is specific to Python - extensions I have installed for this include pylance (python extension pack). The only other extension installed which might be relevant is IntelliCode (microsoft)

This appears to be related to the extension pylance.
More specifically, it seem as if the behaviour only occurs when the setting

Python: Language Server

is set to 'default'.
Setting this manually to Pylance seems to fix the issue.
Edit: Spoke to soon. Issue is still present when set to Pylance
